# WooCommerce change billing, shipping fields not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I would like to change the shipping/billing fields on my checkout page. I found a lot of tutorials, but nothing happens, when I put it in my functions.php file. My main goal is to make all the fields optional, but I can't even change the label, or placeholder of the fields. I tried unset too, but nothing happens.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'bbloomer_rename_woo_checkout_fields' );

function bbloomer_rename_woo_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['shipping_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'New placeholder';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'New label';
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Those hooks mostly work only for checkout template based theme, not for checkout block theme…